# How to install new instance on SQL Server using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is there nay way that my application could create a new instance (say MyInstance) and attach my DB to that, with sa password?

Please give me vb.net code for it if possible.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so!
You can only create an instance through SQL Server installation, there is no code for that.

The attachment yes can be done through code, you just need to add `FOR ATTACH` on your `CREATE DATABASE` command.

Can you share why you want to create a new instance? I don't see why this would be necessary on a application.

Comment: The reason why I need my own instance is so my DB could be attached to that without knowing sa password.  I have seen several articles over net which tell you how to do it, but got stuck at certain stage.  Please refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28188/NET-Installer-that-Automatically-Installs-SQL-200

Comment: This not only installs the SQL server express automatically but also installs new instance and attached DB without involving sa

Comment: You want to install a new instance of SQL purely to rest the SA password?  Why not give the user a username/password dialogue so they can enter the sa password?

Comment: Yes, u are right Rene but I want to explore how making a new instance works.  Anyway, your idea is not bad either.